# For loop: Count matches and unique elements among two dataframes and apply function to counts

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to conduct a very involved loop. I have multiple regions, each with hundreds of plots in my real data frame. I would like to subset by region and then plot and preform various functions on the subsets to ultimately calculate dissimilarity owed to only species that are shared.  I will preface by saying each row is representative of an interaction.

My example `df`:

```
 set.seed(540)
 df<- data.frame(region= c(rep(1, 16), rep(2,8)), 
            plot= c(rep("A",5), rep("B",9), rep("C", 2), rep("D", 6),rep("E", 2)), 
            plantsp= sample(1:24,24, replace= TRUE), 
            lepsp= sample(1:24,24,replace= TRUE), 
            psitsp= sample(1:24,24,replace= TRUE))
 df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
 df$plantsp<-paste('plantsp', df$plantsp, sep='_')
 df$lepsp<-paste('lepsp', df$lepsp, sep='_')
 df$psitsp<-paste('psitsp', df$psitsp, sep='_')
 df$paste1<- paste(df$plantsp, df$lepsp, sep='_')
 df$paste2<- paste(df$lepsp, df$psitsp, sep='_')
 df$paste3<- paste(df$plantsp,df$lepsp, df$psitsp)
```

Step1: Subset df by region. Example:

```
region_sub <- split(df, df$region)
```

Step2: Subset df by plot. Example:

```
plot_sub <- split(region_sub[[1]], region_sub[[1]][[2]])
```

Step3: We will call each subset (each list component) from the step above a plot subset. In this example I will use the first subset (region1, plotA) as an example for all subsequent outputs. I will call this region1, plotA subset  `plot_sub1`. I want to compare `plot_sub1` to the original `df` to make three `df` subsets. We will call these `df_sub1`, `df_sub2`, `df_sub3`. First, `df_sub1` consists of matches among entries in the `plantsp`, `lepsp` columns among `plot_sub1` and `df`. Rows with any unique entries are removed, as well as and rows where a `plantsp` match, but not the `lepsp` and visa versa. Example of `df_sub1`:

```
df_sub1<- df[c(1,2,3,4,5,22),c(1:4,6)]
```

Notice, only those rows with shared species remain. Further, only those rows with shared species that also interact remain. Also, I have removed unnecessary columns (e.g. `psitsp`, `paste2`, `paste3`) to draw your attention to the results of this step. These columns do not need to be removed for the code.

Step4: Repeat step3 for `lepsp` and `psitsp` columns to make `df_sub2`. Example:

```
df_sub2<- df[1:5,c(1:2,4,5,7)]
```

Step5: Repeat step3 for `plantsp`,`lepsp` and `psitsp` column to make `df_sub3`. Example:

```
df_sub3<- df[1:5,c(1:5,8)]
```

Step6: Now that all subsets are made, I want to count matching elements in the `paste1` column among `plot_sub1` and `df_sub1` (=5). Example: 
This would be stored in a vector `match`. The results  will be stored in the match or unique vector, accordingly.  Example:

```
match<- length(intersect(df_sub1$paste1,  plot_sub[[1]]$paste1))
match
```

I also want to count the unique elements (=1). This would be stored in a vector `unique`. This will be repeated for `plot_sub1` and `df_sub2`and `plot_sub1` and `df_sub3`. I am not sure how to count unique elements among two df so I cannot offer example code for that.

```
 unique<- 1
```

Note: Matches among `plot_sub` only need to be counted 1 time in the event the `df_sub` has repeated interactions or matches. This needs to account for presence- absence of matches, not the abundance.

In summary for this subset, the two vectors would be:

```
match<- c( length(intersect(df_sub1$paste1,  plot_sub[[1]]$paste1)),  
length(intersect(df_sub2$paste2,  plot_sub[[1]]$paste2)),  
length(intersect(df_sub3$paste3,  plot_sub[[1]]$paste3))

match

unique<-c(1,0,0)
```

The sum will then be totaled for each vector. Example:

```
sum_match<- 15
sum_unique<- 1
```

Step7: Lastly, these values would be input into a function: 
       ((a + b)/((2*a + b)/2) - 1)   Where a= `sum_match` and b=`sum_unique`. 
       The value is then input into the result vector `res_vec`.

Step8: This process (step3-7) would be iterated for each plot subset.

Effectively, this will calculate the dissimilarity of shared interactions among plot interactions and the corresponding metaweb (all possible interactions). This is a modification from (Poisot et al 2012) to account for tritrophic interactions.

It's quite pathetic, but to start the for loop I have:

```
res_vec<- NA

for (i in 1:length(unique(df$region)))
  {
      for (j in 1:length(unique(df$plot)))
     {
```

I really appreciate any time one is willing to help me realize the arguments within the loop. That is where it gets tricky for me.

Comment: I appreciate the reproducible example, but I am confused by the logic for  `df_sub1`. In your example, you say that `df_sub1` should include row 22 of `df` which has `plantsp_9` and "lepsp_2". However no row in `plot_sub1` has both of those values. Thus, I do not understand why `df[22, ]` is included in `df_sub1`. Further, `df[16, ]` has `plantsp_21` and `lepsp_19`, which exactly matches `plot_sub1[2, ]`, so I also do not understand why `df[16, ]` is not included in `df_sub1`.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with "Rows with any unique entries are removed", which I also do not understand in this context as all the rows of `df[c(1,2,3,4,5,22),c(1:4,6)] ` are unique, and within the `plantsp` column only `plantsp_9` is repeated, the other four values are unique within `df_sub1`

Comment: I appreciate your questions rather than giving up on my question! Your question is a good one, and why my analysis (in my opinion) is pretty cool. To answer  your first question: in row 22 of `df_sub1` while plantsp9 and lepsp2 do not interact in `plot_sub1`, they are both found in that plot. So I want to know, of the subset of species they share, what is interacting differently. By including row22 I am accounting for shared species that interact differently and I need to count those instances.

Comment: I do not consider  `df[16,]` in my example because that is part of plot C which is part of the 3rd iteration of the loop. I need to repeat  steps 3-7  separately for each plot subset (e.g. in the next iteration of the loop will be `plot_sub2` with its corresponding `df_sub1`, `df_sub2`,`df_sub3`, and the third iteration is `plot_sub3`with its corresponding `df_sub1`, `df_sub2`,`df_sub3`, etc. .

Comment: Okay, I think I understand better about df row 22 - it is included in `df_sub1` because both its `plantsp` and `lepsp` values occur *somewhere* in `plot_sub1`, even though they don't occur in the same row. Correct?

Comment: I'm still confused why `df[16, ]` is not included in `plot_sub1`. You say it is part of plot C, but `df[22, ]` is part of plot D and it is included. So what makes plot C special in this case?
 When you say *"I want to compare `plot_sub1` to the original `df`"*, why is plot C exempted? Would it be better to say that `df_subX` has all the rows of `plot_subX` as well as any shared species rows from the *other* region, with different plots in the same region not considered?

Comment: Oh shoot! I understand your question...and now please disregard my previous answer.... With `df[16, ]` you are correct that it would be included. However, it is omitted because the plantsp_21 and lepsp_19 was already accounted for in `df[2,]`. I only need each interaction to be represented once in the `df_sub1` so that match counts count presence or absence, I do not want abundance, thus I remove duplicate interactions. If it does not alter how matches would be counted, you can include it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Okay, is this related to "Rows with any unique entries are removed", do you mean "rows with duplicate entries are removed"?

Comment: No. If we consider only `df_sub1`, examples of rows satisfying the statement in question ("rows with any unique...") include: `df[c(6:8, 12:17, 19:21, 23:24), ]`. Of all the plantsp and lepsp in those rows, none are in `plot_sub1`. Then, for the second part of that statement: "as well as and rows where a plantsp match, but not the lepsp and visa versa"  `df[c(9:11,18),]` satisfy that statement because while plantsp_24 is in `plot_sub1` the species it interacts with lepsp_11 is not, so this row can be removed.

Comment: In regards to your question "do you mean "rows with duplicate entries are removed"?" I tried to address this conditional statement by the note that reads "Note: Matches among plot_sub only need to be counted 1 time in the event the df_sub has repeated interactions or matches. This needs to account for presence- absence of matches, not the abundance."

Comment: Okay. I think I understand well enough to attempt a solution. Unfortunately, I have company tonight and I'm traveling tomorrow. I'll try to find some time to write up an answer, but it might be a day or two.

Comment: Well thank you so much. I can't express how much I appreciate your effort. Thank you and enjoy your company. Look forward to your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thans @Gregor for all the clarification you've already done in the comments!

Here is my solution using the the `tidyverse`.

**CODE + EXPLANATION**

```
## Load packages
library(tidyverse)

## Nest data
new_df <- df %>% 
  group_by(region, plot) %>% 
  nest(.key = plot_sub) 

new_df

# A tibble: 5 x 3
#     region   plot         plot_sub
#      <dbl> <fctr>           <list>
#   1      1      A <tibble [5 x 3]>
#   2      1      B <tibble [9 x 3]>
#   3      1      C <tibble [2 x 3]>
#   4      2      D <tibble [6 x 3]>
#   5      2      E <tibble [2 x 3]>
```

The column `plot_sub` contains the same data as the list with the same name in your question. Think of this column as a list of dataframes.

I know write a function to create the `df_sub`'s. This keeps our code more clean, and avoids unecessary repetition. This function will then be applied to our column `plot_sub`

```
# Function to create the df_sub
# Takes the plot_sub, original dataframe (df) and a list of columns, which should be compared
# Returns the desired df_sub with new interactions of species which are in plot_sub
# Only unique interactions are returned

create_df_sub <-  function(plot_sub, df, col_list){
  # Filter df such that it only contains species which are in plot_sub
  for (x in col_list) {
    df <- df[df[[x]] %in% plot_sub[[x]], ]
  }

  # Combine plot_sub and filtered df
  df_sub <- rbind(plot_sub[, col_list], df[, col_list]) 
  # Paste relevant colums together
  df_sub$paste_col <- do.call(paste, c(df_sub[, col_list], sep = '_'))
  # Exclude duplicated values
  df_sub <- df_sub[!duplicated(df_sub$paste_col), ]

  return(df_sub)
}
```

Now I define the columns I want to create the `df_sub` with and then apply the function to the `plot_sub`-column

```
col_list1 <- c('plantsp', 'lepsp')
col_list2 <- c('lepsp', 'psitsp')
col_list3 <- c('plantsp', 'lepsp', 'psitsp')

new_df <- new_df %>% 
  mutate(df_sub1 = map(plot_sub, create_df_sub, df = df, col_list = col_list1), 
         df_sub2 = map(plot_sub, create_df_sub, df = df, col_list = col_list2), 
         df_sub3 = map(plot_sub, create_df_sub, df = df, col_list = col_list3))
```

`map` takes a vector or list as argument and applies the specified function to each element (like `lapply`). Compare the first elements of `df_sub1` and `plot_sub` to see the difference.

```
new_df$plot_sub[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#      plantsp    lepsp    psitsp
#        <chr>    <chr>     <chr>
# 1  plantsp_2 lepsp_19 psitsp_19
# 2 plantsp_21 lepsp_19  psitsp_4
# 3 plantsp_19  lepsp_2 psitsp_11
# 4  plantsp_9 lepsp_13 psitsp_24
# 5 plantsp_24  lepsp_9  psitsp_2

new_df$df_sub1[[1]]
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#      plantsp    lepsp           paste_col
#        <chr>    <chr>               <chr>
# 1  plantsp_2 lepsp_19  plantsp_2_lepsp_19
# 2 plantsp_21 lepsp_19 plantsp_21_lepsp_19
# 3 plantsp_19  lepsp_2  plantsp_19_lepsp_2
# 4  plantsp_9 lepsp_13  plantsp_9_lepsp_13
# 5 plantsp_24  lepsp_9  plantsp_24_lepsp_9
# 6  plantsp_9  lepsp_2   plantsp_9_lepsp_2
```

The new interaction is added in `df_sub1`.

To extract matching and unique values, I use `inner_join` and `anti_join` on the `plot_sub`-column and the different `df_sub`'s

```
new_df <- new_df %>%
  mutate(match1 = map2(df_sub1, plot_sub, inner_join, by = col_list1), 
         match2 = map2(df_sub2, plot_sub, inner_join, by = col_list2), 
         match3 = map2(df_sub3, plot_sub, inner_join, by = col_list3), 
         unique1 = map2(df_sub1, plot_sub, anti_join, by = col_list1), 
         unique2 = map2(df_sub2, plot_sub, anti_join, by = col_list2), 
         unique3 = map2(df_sub3, plot_sub, anti_join, by = col_list3))
```

The `inner_join` returns all rows, which have matching values in the columns specified in the `by`-argument, whereas the `anti_join` returns all rows of `df_sub`, which are not matched. 
Here I use the `map2`-function, which takes two vectors/list and applies the specified function.

```
new_df$match1[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#      plantsp    lepsp    psitsp           paste_col
#        <chr>    <chr>     <chr>               <chr>
# 1  plantsp_2 lepsp_19 psitsp_19  plantsp_2_lepsp_19
# 2 plantsp_21 lepsp_19  psitsp_4 plantsp_21_lepsp_19
# 3 plantsp_19  lepsp_2 psitsp_11  plantsp_19_lepsp_2
# 4  plantsp_9 lepsp_13 psitsp_24  plantsp_9_lepsp_13
# 5 plantsp_24  lepsp_9  psitsp_2  plantsp_24_lepsp_9

new_df$unique1[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#     plantsp   lepsp         paste_col
#       <chr>   <chr>             <chr>
# 1 plantsp_9 lepsp_2 plantsp_9_lepsp_2
```

In the last step I extract the number of rows of each `match` and `unique` and sum it up. I also calculate the `res_vec`.

```
new_df <- new_df %>%
  mutate(sum_match = map_int(match1, nrow) + map_int(match2, nrow) + map_int(match3, nrow), 
         sum_unique = map_int(unique1, nrow) + map_int(unique2, nrow) + map_int(unique3, nrow), 
         res_vec = ((sum_match + sum_unique)/((2*sum_match + sum_unique)/2)) - 1)
```

Here I use `map_int` as my return value is an integer and I want to directly use it in a sum. Using `map` only would return a list which I first have to convert to a integer vector.

```
new_df %>% select(region, plot, sum_match, sum_unique, res_vec)
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#   region   plot sum_match sum_unique    res_vec
#    <dbl> <fctr>     <int>      <int>      <dbl>
# 1      1      A        15          1 0.03225806
# 2      1      B        27          3 0.05263158
# 3      1      C         6          2 0.14285714
# 4      2      D        18          1 0.02702703
# 5      2      E         6          0 0.00000000
```

**DATA**

```
set.seed(540)
df <- data.frame(region = c(rep(1, 16), rep(2, 8)), 
                plot = c(rep('A', 5), rep('B', 9), rep('C', 2), rep('D', 6),rep('E', 2)), 
                plantsp = sample(1:24, 24, replace = TRUE), 
                lepsp = sample(1:24, 24, replace = TRUE), 
                psitsp = sample(1:24, 24, replace = TRUE))
df$plantsp <- paste('plantsp', df$plantsp, sep = '_')
df$lepsp <- paste('lepsp', df$lepsp, sep = '_')
df$psitsp <- paste('psitsp', df$psitsp, sep = '_')
```

Comment: Wow. I am so thankful and impressed. This works great. The only minor fix is the `res_vec`  formula. It is not calculating the answer correctly. `res_vec` should be `res_vec <- c(0.032, 0.052, 0.143, 0.027, 0)`. That was my error and I will edit in my post. If you update your answer to `res_vec = ((sum_match + sum_unique)/((2*sum_match + sum_unique)/2)) - 1) ` it will be the correct answer.

Comment: I have not run this on my real data. Any idea if this method or a loop will be faster? It will be a huge data set this is run on (i.e over 9 regions and 1500 plots) and I am curious how quickly your solution will run in comparison to a loop.

Comment: I guess this is faster than a loop but you can use `microbenchmark` to first compare different approaches and then choose the fastest one.

Comment: This is a great solution and thanks for the `microbenchmark` suggestion, I wasn't aware of it and that will help a lot.  I have updated my OP to account for my mistake, so I advise you update your answer. Thank you for all the time you put into this.

Comment: Very nice! I was feeling bead for not getting an answer together yet - glad you got to it!

Comment: @kath How would you adapt this for pairwise comparisons among each plot_sub (as opposed to plot_sub and df_sub) ? I have posted a different question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58295133/return-counts-of-matches-and-unique-items-for-all-pairwise-comparisons-within-su