# Return counts of matches and unique items for all pairwise comparisons within subsets

Tags: r, for-loop, match, unique, tidyverse

I have a data frame of plant `plantsp` and herbivore `lepsp` species and their  interactions `int1` and `int2` with sampling nested in `site`, `season` and `group` . I wish to create a loop that makes pairwise comparisons among each level of `group` collected  within each `site` and `season` subset. Fore each pairwise comparison I will calculate total MATCHING and UNIQUE interactions among `int1` and `int2`. I have devised the following steps to break down this problem:

Consider the following example data frame `df`:

```
sub<-data.frame(site= rep(1, 8),  
           season=rep("wet", 8), 
           group= c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3), 
           plantsp= c("P1", "P1", "P2", "P1", "P2", "P1", "P2","P2"),
           lepsp= c("L3", "L1", "L2",  "L1", "L2", "L1", "L1","L2"),
           psitsp=c(NA, "psit1",  NA, NA,NA, NA,NA, NA))

sub2<-data.frame(site= rep(1, 8),  
             season=rep("dry", 8), 
             group= c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3), 
             plantsp= c("P1", "P1", "P2", "P1", "P2", "P1", "P2","P2"),
             lepsp= c("L3", "L1", "L2",  "L1", "L2", "L1", "L1","L2"),
             psitsp=c(NA, "psit1",  NA, NA,NA, NA,NA, NA))

sub3<-data.frame(site= rep(2, 8),  
             season=rep("wet", 8), 
             group= c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3), 
             plantsp= c("P1", "P1", "P2", "P1", "P2", "P1", "P2","P2"),
             lepsp= c("L3", "L1", "L2",  "L1", "L2", "L1", "L1","L2"),
             psitsp=c(NA, "psit1",  NA, NA,NA, NA,NA, NA))

sub4<-data.frame(site= rep(2, 8),  
             season=rep("dry", 8), 
             group= c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3), 
             plantsp= c("P1", "P1", "P2", "P1", "P2", "P1", "P2","P2"),
             lepsp= c("L3", "L1", "L2",  "L1", "L2", "L1", "L1","L2"),
             psitsp=c(NA, "psit1",  NA, NA,NA, NA,NA, NA))
df<- rbind(sub, sub2, sub3, sub4)

df$int1<- paste( df$plantsp, df$lepsp, sep="_")
df$int2<-paste( df$lepsp, df$psitsp, sep="_")
df
```

**Step 1:** Subset `df` by `site` and `season`. Example:

```
sub1<- split(df,list(df$site, df$season))
sub1
```

**Step 2:** Subset `df` by `group`. Example:

```
sub2 <- split(sub1[[1]], sub1[[1]][[3]])
sub2
```

**Step 3:** We will call each list element in `sub2` a group. Example:

```
#group1 
group1<-sub2[1]
group1
#group2
group2<-sub2[2]
group2
```

**Step 4:** I want to make pairwise comparisons among each `group`. For each pairwise comparison I want to create vectors that summarize counts of UNIQUE and MATCHING elements among `int1` and `int2`. This will be iterated though `df` for all possible pairwise comparisons among all groups for all subsets. Example for `group1` and `group2`:

```
#CALCULATE MATCHING ELEMENTS

#Count matches in `int1` among both levels of `group`
match1<- length(intersect(sub2[[1]][[7]],  sub2[[2]][[7]])) # P1_L1 & P2_L2
match1

#Count matches in `int2` among  both levels of `group`. Exclude `int1` or `int2` with  NAs
temp<-lapply(sub2, na.omit)
temp

match2<- length(intersect(temp[[1]][[8]],temp[[2]][[8]]))
match2

#SUM `match1` and `match2` and put result into vector called `vecA`.
#`vecA`: represents vector of sums of the counts of MATCHING items in 
# both groups within `int1` AND `int2` columns.

vecA<-sum(match1, match2)
vecA

#CALCULATE UNIQUE ELEMENTS TO GROUP1

#Count unique items  in `int1` within the first level of `group`
unique_int1<- df[1,] # P1_L3
unique_int1<- length(unique_int1$int1)

#Count unique items  in `int2` within the first level of `group`
unique_int2<- df[2,] #L1_psit1
unique_int2<- length(unique_int2$int2)

#SUM `unique_int1` and `unique_int2` and put result into vector called 
#`vecB`.`vecB`:  represents vector of sums of `int1` AND `int2` that 
#are UNIQUE to `group1` in the pairwise comparison  

vecB<-sum(unique_int1, unique_int2)
vecB

#CALCULATE UNIQUE ELEMENTS TO GROUP2

#Count unique items  in `int1`  to `group2`
unique_int1<- 0 

#Count unique items  in `int2` within the first level of `group`
unique_int2<- 0


#SUM `unique1_int1` and `unique1_int2` and put result into vector 
#called `vecC`.`vecC`:  represents vector of sums of `int1` AND `int2` 
#that are UNIQUE to `group2` in the pairwise comparison  
vecC<-sum(unique_int1, unique_int2)
vecC
```

The expected result for all pairwise comparisons for all subsets given `df` and the steps above is:

```
result1<-data.frame(site= c(rep(1, 6),rep(2, 6)),  
               season=c(rep("wet", 3), rep("dry", 3), rep("wet", 3), rep("dry", 3)),
               group_pairs= c("1_2", "2_3", "1_3", "1_2", "2_3", "1_3","1_2", "2_3", "1_3", "1_2", "2_3", "1_3"),
               vecA= c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
               vecB= c(2,0,2,2,0,2,2,0,2,2,0,2),
               vecC=c(0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0))
```

**Step 5:** Conduct steps above but ONLY for species present in BOTH levels of `group`.

```
 #CALCULATE MATCHING ELEMENTS 

 #If `plantsp` OR  `lepsp`  match among both levels of `group`,count matches in `int1`. 

 match1<- length(intersect(sub2[[1]][[7]],  sub2[[2]][[7]]))
 match1

# If `lepsp` OR `psitsp`  match among both levels of `group`, count matches in `int2`. Remove NAs
  temp<-lapply(sub2, na.omit)
  temp     
  match2<- length(intersect(temp[[1]][[8]],  temp[[2]][[8]]))
  match2

#SUM `match1` and `match2` above and put result into vector called `vecD`. `vecD`: vector of sums of MATCHING items in `int1` and `int2` after subsetting for those species both levels of group share. 
 vecD<- sum(match1, match2) 

#CALCULATE UNIQUE ELEMENTS TO GROUP1
# If `plantsp` OR `lepsp`   match among both levels of `group`, count unique items  in `int1`. This is represented by the P1_L3 interaction in `int1`
 unique_int1<-1 

# If `lepsp` and `psitsp`   match among both levels of `group`, count unique items  in `int2`. This is represented by the L1_psit1 interaction in `int2`
 unique_int2<-1

# SUM `unique_int1` and `unique_int2` above and put result into vector called `vecE`. `vecE`: vector of sums of UNIQUE items to the FIRST level of `group` included in the pairwise comparison after after subsetting for those species both levels of group share. 
vecE<- sum(unique_int1, unique_int2)

#CALCULATE UNIQUE ELEMENTS TO GROUP2
# If `plantsp` OR `lepsp`   match among both levels of `group`, count unique items  in `int1`. 
 unique_int1<-0 

# If `lepsp` and `psitsp`   match among both levels of `group`, count unique items  in `int2`. 
 unique_int2<-0

# SUM `unique_int1` and `unique_int2` above and put result into vector called `vecF`. `vecF`: vector of sums of UNIQUE items to the SECOND level of `group` included in the pairwise comparison after after subsetting for those species both levels of group share. 
vecE<- sum(unique_int1, unique_int2)
```

The expected result for all pairwise comparisons for all subsets given `df` and the steps above is:

```
result2<-data.frame(site= c(rep(1, 6),rep(2, 6)),  
               season=c(rep("wet", 3), rep("dry", 3), rep("wet", 3), rep("dry", 3)),
               group_pairs= c("1_2", "2_3", "1_3", "1_2", "2_3", "1_3","1_2", "2_3", "1_3", "1_2", "2_3", "1_3"),
               vecD= c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
               vecE= c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
               vecF=c(0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1))
```

A similar question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47719961/for-loop-count-matches-and-unique-elements-among-two-dataframes-and-apply-funct), however this approach is unique for all pairwise comparisons among groups.

Comment: What have you tried? I'm not clear where you're having trouble. As currently phrased, this seems like a long spec.

Comment: I tried various iterations of the accepted answer on the  link I included in the OP. I was hesitant to add more text to this post and opted not to show this. Please advise if you would like to see ~30 lines of code added.

Comment: No, this already looked too long for me to be able to help. Good luck!

Comment: This would probably be easier to help with if it were split into separate questions with each discrete problem. The *minimal* part of [mcve] is good advice, not just for us to help you debug, but also for yourself to more closely identify and tease apart the code

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I can't follow all the steps of this question, but I hope this gets you started.

Here's a way to get all the pairwise matches of `int1` between different `group`s within each `site` + `season`. This is accomplished by joining a list of all the existing `site` / `season` / `group` / `int1` combinations with itself. That way we get a row for every pair of groups with matching site/season/int1. Then we can limit those to non-matching groups in ascending order, and count the number of rows that are produced for each set we're tracking. The last `unite` step renames the two group columns into one.

```
 library(tidyverse)
  df %>%
    distinct(site, season, group, int1) -> temp
  left_join(temp, temp, by = c("site", "season", "int1")) %>%
    filter(group.x < group.y, !is.na(int1)) %>%
    count(site, season, group.x, group.y, name = "vecD") %>%
    unite(group_pairs, c(group.x, group.y))

# A tibble: 12 x 4
    site season group_pairs  vecD
   <dbl> <fct>  <chr>       <int>
 1     1 wet    1_2             2
 2     1 wet    1_3             2
 3     1 wet    2_3             2
 4     1 dry    1_2             2
 5     1 dry    1_3             2
 6     1 dry    2_3             2
 7     2 wet    1_2             2
 8     2 wet    1_3             2
 9     2 wet    2_3             2
10     2 dry    1_2             2
11     2 dry    1_3             2
12     2 dry    2_3             2
```

Comment: Is there a step in particular I can make more clear? The output seems correct for `vecA` but `vecA` or `vecD` should take the sum of matches in `int1` and `int2`. Your solution only seems to count matches in `int1`. Also,  how could you modify this code to sum unique elements in `int1` and `int2` to each group?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table).

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, 
     {
       groups <- combn(unique(group), 2)

       group_pairs = apply(groups, 2, paste, collapse = '_')
       vecA = apply(groups, 2, FUN = function(x) length(intersect(group, x[1])) + length(intersect(group, x[2])))

       #apply(groups, 2, function(x) .SD[group %in% x, print(.SD)])

       list(group_pairs = group_pairs, vecA = vecA)
     }
     , 
   by = .(site, season)]

    site season group_pairs vecA
 1:    1    wet         1_2    2
 2:    1    wet         1_3    2
 3:    1    wet         2_3    2
 4:    1    dry         1_2    2
 5:    1    dry         1_3    2
 6:    1    dry         2_3    2
 7:    2    wet         1_2    2
 8:    2    wet         1_3    2
 9:    2    wet         2_3    2
10:    2    dry         1_2    2
11:    2    dry         1_3    2
12:    2    dry         2_3    2
```

Note for `vecA` I steal your code. Unfortunately, your code doesn't have similar explanations for `vecB` and so on. It's just simply states `unique_int1 <- 1; unique_int2 <- 1; vecB<-sum(unique_int1, unique_int2)` with no equation.

Here's the data itself for `group1`:

```
> group1
$`1`
  site season group plantsp lepsp psitsp  int1     int2
1    1    wet     1      P1    L3   <NA> P1_L3    L3_NA
2    1    wet     1      P1    L1  psit1 P1_L1 L1_psit1
3    1    wet     1      P2    L2   <NA> P2_L2    L2_NA
```

If you uncomment out the `apply` line in my code, you get the following printout (truncated for brevity):

```
#site 1, season == wet
   group plantsp lepsp psitsp  int1     int2
1:     1      P1    L3   <NA> P1_L3    L3_NA
2:     1      P1    L1  psit1 P1_L1 L1_psit1
3:     1      P2    L2   <NA> P2_L2    L2_NA
4:     2      P1    L1   <NA> P1_L1    L1_NA
5:     2      P2    L2   <NA> P2_L2    L2_NA
```

Maybe you can take that `apply()` statement and run with it.

Comment: Thank you for your  solution for `vecA`. In hopes you can update your post with solutions for calculating `vecB` and `vecC` as well,  I have edited the OP so it is more clear which rows in `df` contribute to `vecB` and `vecC`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still do not follow. For ```vecB``` you are always subsetting a single row to evaluate ```int1``` and ```int2``` so the answer would be always 2.